# How location.global_relative_frame.alt measure altitude?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, drone.io, dronekit-python

I'm working on a Drone project with a Raspberry Pi connected with the Pixhawk4 via MAVLink protocol.

I'm trying to understand how the following method is measuring the altitude of the drone:

`my_drone.location.global_relative_frame.alt`

Maybe it is using the barometer, but is there a way to change the measure way to the GPS?

Here is the [documentation](https://dronekit-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/automodule.html#dronekit.Vehicle.location), but I didn't find anything.

Comment: Please provide specifics on the problem. Code examples and logs at least, with a particular question or issue to address. A link to ALL the documentation is not appropriate.